# ViewPager : scrolling event is consumed by the page ahead and not the current page

Tags: android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling

My problem is that in my project, there is a `list` in a `fragment` that has, say 10 items. I have to open a **second** `fragment` on a click of any item on this `list`.

On this **second** `fragment`, I have to show a `view pager` with the same contents as that of the `list` in the **first**, with the difference that it is also having the details of that `item` *(several views to describe the title `item`, that was selected/clicked in the `list`)*. Hence the both the `fragments` have the same number of items and in the same sequence, on one to one basis.

**Second fragment *(description)*:**

I have a `view pager` that I am using with `ViewPagerAdapter` *(That which you use with `views` and not `Fragments`)*.

When I click on the **9th** `item` on the `first fragment` *(list)*, the **9th** `page` in the second fragment *(view pager)* is opened.

Everything runs perfectly till the backward swipe *(right swipe)* is done.

Click on the **9th** `item` as an example on the `list`. Now start swiping backward, on the `view pager`, i.e. **right swipe**. On each previous page, I observe that `vertical scroll` in the middle region of the `page` is not possible, as it was in the `pages ahead` of it.

[**Note:** `Vertical scrolling` that I have given works by having `ScrollView`
 over `LinearLayout` that has all the other items in each `page` of the
 `ViewPager`.]

**My Observations:**

**Observation 1:** You do not get `vertical scroll freeze` when swiping in the forward direction *(swipe to left)*.

**Observation 2:** You can still scroll vertically when it is frozen, while you are trying to do it on the `vertical scroll bar` that is provided on the right edge of the screen.

**Observation 3:** When you are trying to `scroll` on the `frozen page` in the `view pager`, actually the page after it is scrolling *(**10th** page will scroll, when you are scrolling from the **9th**, and the page is frozen on the **9th**)*.

Just scroll on the frozen page and swipe to the next page, and you find that the `next page scroll state` is changed.

On swiping, there is no inconsistency in the pages and the position.

**Question Summary:** **How to allow scroll on the current screen *(opened on right swipe)* and prevent it to happen concurrently on the next page *(opened on left swipe)*, on the `ViewPager`where each page
has its `ScrollView`.**

Please help me out.

Comment: I am using instantiate items method as shown in the samples. I want to know whether there is a convert view style to know whether the item was previously initialized? Is there a read ahead (two or more items created simultaneously) ?

Comment: There is a getChildAt(position) method. It returns null if the view is not initialized as yet. Three items are initialized at once (one is current, others are before and after). If you scroll over the edges, or scrollbar, the scroll is successful, otherwise the event is consumed in the page that is below (ahead).

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355274/change-quote-formatting-to-show-double-quote-marks/355299#355299 regarding the (ab-)use of blockquotes....

Comment: @piet.t : Thanks Sir, I have reviewed and changed the formats accordingly. Wherever I have not quoted some text from external sources, I have changed that portion to bold text to emphasize. Please don't remove my signature from the posts. I hope that's not abusive.